# Update multiple rows with different keys in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have this table

**inventory**

```
id | name  | location | quantity    
1  | test  | loc1     | 0    
2  | test  | loc2     | 0    
3  | test2 | loc1     | 0    
4  | test2 | loc2     | 0
```

I want to update

test loc 1 with quantity 50

and

test2 loc2 with quantity 100

how do I it?

I have tried using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but it doesn't work it just creates new rows
here's the guide I used [ITS ON #3](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/11/how-to-update-multiple-rows-at-once-in-mysql.html)

I'm using javascript (nodejs)

Comment: did you try reading any documentation for updating tables in MySQL?  https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/update.php

Comment: Also show us what have you tried.

Comment: *I have tried using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but it doesn't work it just creates new rows* `INSERT .. ODKU` needs in unique index for successfull working.